# How to Implement Web Push Notification for incoming calls

Tags: javascript, web, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, web-push

I am creating a video/audio calling web app and want to show users an incoming call notification just like it would show in a native calling app

So, is there a way to implement it?

I know I can implement simple push notifications but that is different from what a notification for an incoming call would look like.

when an incoming call comes in a native app, the phone's ringtone starts playing and the notification stays there until the call timeout happens or the user makes an action.

so I need something like that.

I have a nodejs server with a client app

Comment: You cannot trigger native call action from web apps. However, you can create an app that uses web push to notify users about a call, and show a call-like UI when your application is open in their browser.

Comment: so I can't get that ringing sound?

i wanted that in case user's phone is locked or at idle and if the notification cames then the user will not notice it but if the phone will ring or play sound then user will notice the notification and accept the call

Comment: WebApps don't have access to the device's core APIs. You can instead try to create a Cordova app which can expose these API's to some extent.